# Add one group to NTFS permission without disrupting other permissions

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, ntfs

I have a large and messy shared drive to which I need to give one user (group) read only access throughout.

This has grown over the years and has hundreds of groups with varying levels of access and inheritance turned off at various points in the structure. Groups with list access were used at the first level of folders but beyond that it has descended into chaos.

Is there a means of adding one group at the root of the folder structure and adding that group with read permission to every object within? What I don't want to do is overwrite all the permissions with what I set at the root level, and it seems this will happen if I propagate this to child objects.

This should obviously have happened from the beginning, but that was years ago...

Advice would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: icacls is what you want to use in this case. - http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will take a look. I don't think it's going to be simple though. Many of the folders I don't even have access to and so need to take ownership first, which in itself might cause problems.